# Is limit of null-homotopic maps null-homotopic?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds

The question is motivated by my failed [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356253/non-density-of-continuous-functions-to-interior-in-set-of-all-continuous-functio#comment895364_356253) to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356253/non-density-of-continuous-functions-to-interior-in-set-of-all-continuous-functio).

Let $M$ and $N$ be path connected locally compact, locally contractible metric spaces (you may assume that they are manifolds).

Let $\varphi_{n}:M\to N$ be null-homotopic and convergent to $\varphi:M\to N$ in the compact open topology.

> Does it follow that $\varphi$ is null-homotopic?

Note that homotopy between maps is a **path** in $C(M,N)$ (for nice $M$, $N$), and so what my question asks is whether the path component of a constant map is closed in $C(M,N)$.

I am waaay out of my depth here, but perhaps there is a continuous or positive lower semi-continuous functional on $C(M,N)$ akin to the topological degree such that null-homotopic maps would be the zero-set of that functional?

Comment: Maybe try: Take $\phi_0=*$ the constant map and write homotopies $\phi_i \sim \phi_{i+1}$, and run them during time $[1/(i+2), 1/(i+1)]$ this defines a map $M\times (0,1] \to N$ which you can complete(?) to $M\times[0,1] \to N$ placing $\phi$ at time $0$. (I don't anything about topology, so maybe there's some point set horror that makes this not work).

Comment: @DylanWilson yeah on principle your argument is like this: you have a convergent sequence in the same path component, then take a long path that runs through all these points, and voila. However (again this is just why this argument doesn't work on principle, i hope it does in this situation), if your space is the topologist's sine curve this long path is jut too long to converge.

Comment: If $M,N$ are manifolds then they have CW homotopy type. Thus if $M$ is compact, then $C(M,N)$ (compact-open topology) has CW homotopy type (this is Milnor). In particular it is locally contractible, so locally path connected, so the path components coincide with the connected components and are clopen.

Comment: @Tyrone Local contractibility is not a homotopy invariant. For example, a comb space is homotopy equivalent to a point, but is not locally connected.

Comment: @ConnorMalin you're right, locally contractible is not enough, but the statement still stands: it is enough that the $C(M,N)$ is homotopy equivalent to a space which admits an ambiently contractible open covering - this property is homotopy invariant.

Comment: @Tyrone Ah I see, a continuous map induces a continuous map between topologized path components and a homotopy equivalence induces a bijection on path components, so in fact the homotopy equivalence induces a homeomorphism on the topologized path components.

Comment: @ConnorMalin, to clarify, I was half assuming that 'manifold' means 'smooth manifold', in which case $M,N$ are CW complexes, so the local contractibility statement applies. If $M,N$ are only $C^0$ and of dimensions not equal to $4$, then they are homeomorphic to CW complexes, so the statement applies again. In the case that it is $4$-dimensional, then it is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex (it is not known in general if it is homeomorphic). If it is compact then it is homotopy equivalent to a finite CW complex. Thus even in this case $C(M,N)$ is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex.

Comment: In this case, as you point out, the local contractiblity statement I made is not necessarily true, but a CW complex admits a (numerable) ambiently contractible open covering (I have in mind that it is a Dold space). Such a covering guarantees that its path components are open. Since such a covering may be pulled back along a homotopy equivalence, this guarantees that anything homotopy equivalent to a CW complex has open path components (although it need not be locally contractible - for instance the comb space).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll provide a general theorem (then one has to apply it to specific circumstances). There is a micro-dictionary/Notation at the bottom of this note.

**B-assumption**:   Space $\ N\times N\times[0;1]\ $ is normal.

Every metric space $\ N\ $ satisfies **B-assumption**.

**Notation**   Let $\ \mathcal W_N\ $ be the set of all closed
neighborhoods of diagonal $\ \Delta_N\ :=\ \{(y\ y):\ y\in N\}\ $
in $\ N\times N.$

Family $\ \mathcal W_N\ $ is a basis of all neighborhoods of the diagonal $\ \Delta_N.$

**A-assumption**:   Space $\ N\ $ is an ANR, meaning that
for every normal space $\ X\ $ and closed subset $\ A\ $ of $\ X,\ $
and for every continuous function $\ f:A\to N\ $ there exists
a neighborhood $\ U\ $ of $\ A\ $ and continuous $\ F:U\to N\ $ such
that $\ F|A=f.$

Thus, $\ N^2\ $ is an ANR too.

**Definition**:   Sequence $\ f_n:M\to N\ $ is d-convergent to
$\ f:M\to N\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow $

$$ \forall_{V\in\mathcal W_N}\exists_{m\in\Bbb N}
     \forall_{n\ge m}\quad (f_n\triangle f)(M)\,
       \subseteq V $$

Only continuous functions are meant:

**THEOREM**   Let sequence $\ f_n:M\to N\ $ be d-convergent
to $\ f:M\to N.\ $ Then there exists $\ m\in\Bbb N\ $ such that
$\ f_n\ $ and $\ f\ $ are homotopic for every $\ n\ge m.$

**PROOF**   Diagonal $\ \Delta_N\ $ is an ANR because it is
homeomorphic to $\ N.\ $ Also, $\ \Delta_N\ $ is closed in $\ N^2\ $ since $\ N\ $ is Hausdorff.  Thus, there exists $\ U\in\mathcal W_N\ $
and a retraction $\ \rho:U\to\Delta_N\ $ (it is an extension of the
identity map on $\ \Delta_N.)$

Consider the function $\ g\ $ from a closed subset of $\ N^2\times[0;1]\ $ into $\ N^2\ $ given as follows:

- $\ \forall_{y\in N^2}\quad g(y\ 0)\ :=\ y; $
- $\ \forall_{y\in\Delta_N}\forall_{t\in[0;1]}
           \quad g(y\ t)\ := y; $
- $\ \forall_{y\in U}\qquad g(y\ 1)\ :=\ \rho(y). $

The arguments of $\ g\ $ belong to the union of three closed subsets
of $\ N\times[0;1],\ $ where the three parts of the definition of
$\ g\ $ coincide on the overlaps hence $\ g\ $ is well defined. This
$\ g\ $ admits an extension  $\ G_0\ $ over a closed neighborhood of its closed $3$-part domain. This neighborhood includes $\ V\times[0;1],\ $ where $\ V\subseteq U\ $ is a closed neighborhood of $\ \Delta_N,\ $
because $\ [0;1]\ $ is compact.

Now, by (very elementary and great) Borsuk's homotopy extension
theorem, there is homotopy

$$ H:N^2\times[0;1]\to N^2 $$

such that:

- $\ \forall_{y\in N^2}\qquad H(y\ 0)\ :=\ y; $
- $\ \forall_{y\in V}\forall_{t\in[0;1]}
           \quad H(y\ t)\ := G_0(y\ t); $

Let $\ m\in\Bbb N\ $ and $\ n\ge m\ $ be as in
**Definition**. Let homotopies
$\ h_n\ h:M\times[0;1]\to N\ $ be given as

$$ h_n\ :=\ \pi'\circ H\circ
          ((f_n\triangle f)\times\Bbb I );$$
$$ h\ :=\ \pi''\circ H\circ
          ((f_n\triangle f)\times\Bbb I );$$

where $\ \pi'\ \pi'':N^2\to N\ $ are the canonical projections,
and $\ \Bbb I:[0;1]\to[0;1]\ $ is the identity map.
We see that:

$$ \forall_{x\in M}\quad h_n(x\ 0)\ =\ f_n(x); $$
$$ \forall_{x\in M}\quad h(x\ 0)\ =\ f(x); $$
$$ \forall_{x\in M}\quad h_n(x\ 1)\ =\ h(x\ 1). $$

Define $\ \gamma_n:M\to Y\ $ by $\ \gamma_n(x):=h_n(x\ 1)=h(x\ 1).\ $
We see that $\ f_n\ $ is homotopic to $\ \gamma_n\ $ is homotopic
to $\ f.\,\ $ Remember (observe) that $\ H\ $ in the expressions for
$\ h_n(x\ 1)\ $ and $\ h(x\ 1)\ $ is equal to $\ G_0\ $ (we have
$\ (f_n(x)\ f(x))\in V).\ $   ***End of PROOF***

---

**NOTATION**

- For functions $\ f:P\to Q\ $ and $\ g:R\to S,\ $ the cartesian product $\ f\times g:P\times Q\to R\times S\ $ is given by
  $$ \forall_{(p\ r)\in P\times R}\quad
           (f\times g)(p\ r)\ :=\ (f(p)\ g(r)\,) $$
- Let $\ P=R\ $ and $\ \Delta_P:=\{(p\ p): p\in P\}.\ $ Then
  $\ f\triangle g: P\to Q\times S\ $ is given as follows:
  $$ f\triangle g\ := (f\times g)\circ \delta_P $$
  where $\ \delta_P:P\to P\times P\ $, and
  $\ \forall_{p\in P}\ \delta_P(p):=(p\ p).$

Comment: As one can see, the argument space M (the source) is ARBITRARY.

Comment: Could you relate your assumption on $N$ to that of the OP (in particular local contractibility)? Could you state whether you claim you're answering the OP's question?

Comment: I assume that $\ N\ $ is an ANR.

Comment: Can you relate ANR and local contractibility? It maybe obvious to you but not to me.

Comment: True, I left some (perhaps even subtle) general consideration untouched. However "ANR assumption" is still very general. The classical fundamental paper by Karol Borsuk showed that in the case of finite-dimensional compact metric spaces, local contractability implies ANR.

Comment: I remember that mathematicians like Dugundji and Hu have studied the general scope of the ANR concept.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have a hard time following it. What is $(f\Delta f_n)$? Is it the cartesian product of $f$ and $f_n$? If it is, is the $d$-convergence the same as uniform convergence in the case when $N$ is metric? When you apply Borsuk's theorem, what is $Y$? Is it supposed to be $N$? Also, which homotopy are you extending? I guess, you assume that $\Delta_N$ is a deformation retract in $U$, right? does it follows from being ANR?

Comment: @erz, I'll add a tiny dictionary. And I'll fix the typo you've spotted, thank you. (It should be N not Y).

Comment: For compact spaces, d-convergence is uniform.

Comment: @erz, for non-compact metric spaces d-convergence, implies uniform convergence but the converse is false.

Comment: Thank you! But why is $\rho$ homotopic to the identity on $U$?

Comment: @erz, at a moment of weakness I've simplified my proof too much. I'll fix it, no sweat. Thank you for your high-quality reading.

Comment: @erz, mathematically -- no sweat, but editing-wise -- torture. I hope I fixed everything (let's keep fingers crossed). #### The proof works in a smaller neighborhood $\ V\ $ hence the **Definition** refers now to $\ V\ $ The **Definition** is (logically) the same but the **Proof** refers to $\ V\ $ hence the convenient trivial modification of the definition.

Comment: I think now I understand. Thank you! I corrected $Y$ to be $N$ in 2 more places. However, this solves a slightly different problem from what I asked: the convergence of functions is different, and I cannot see how to reduce my problem to this one. I'll wait a bit, and if nobody comes up with a compact-open version, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @erz, thank you very much for everything, including fixing $\ Y\to N$ translation (the standard notation $\ f:X\to Y,\ $ with $\ Y\in \text{ANR},\ $ got imprinted in my brain, I guess). I hope that my answer provides a good environment for your topic (even if only partial -- it's always partial :) ).

Answer (score 2):

Please see the answer to Annie's question.
[Non-density of continuous functions to interior in set of all continuous functions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/356253)