# Map which is null-homotopic on compacts

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory, manifolds

This is the missing ingredient towards answering [my previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356475/is-limit-of-null-homotopic-maps-null-homotopic).

Let $M$ and $N$ be path connected locally compact, locally contractible metric spaces (you may assume that they are manifolds). It seems the "correct" condition on $N$ is absolute neighborhood retract. Let us also assume that $M$ is $\sigma$-compact, i.e. a union of a sequence of compact sets (and then we can even assume that every compact set in $M$ is contained in an element of that sequence).

> Let $\varphi:M\to N$ be such that for every compact $K\subset M$ the map $\varphi|_{K}$ is null-homotopic. Does it follow that $\varphi$ is in fact null-homotopic?

The intuition says that if there is a hole in $N$ such that $\varphi$ is wrapped around it, it should be wrapped already on some compact set.

Let me also add a specific case when $\varphi$ is identity map.

> If $N$ is such that the inclusion of every compact $K$ is null-homotopic (meaning $K$ is contractible within $N$), does it follow that $N$ is contractible?

Comment: There exist phantom maps $\mathbb{C}P^\infty\to S^3$. These are non-null homotopic maps which become null-homotopic when restricted to each finite skeleton. Doesn't this answer your question in the negative?

Comment: ANRs are locally contractible.

Comment: @MarkGrant Unfortunately, I am not competent to see if this answers my question. Is $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ locally compact and $\sigma$-compact? Is every compact subset of it included in a finite skeleton?

Comment: A trivial remark: homomorphisms of homotopy groups which are induced by $\ \phi\ $ are trivial.

Comment: @erz Ah, OK, it is more subtle than I thought. It appears that $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ with the weak (CW) topology may not be metrizable, which would imply that it's also not locally compact. I haven't checked, but I assume that the constructions of these phantom maps use the weak topology.

Comment: There is however a metric on $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ for which each inclusion $\mathbb{C}P^n\subseteq\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ is an isometric embedding (Fubini-Study). One could ask if the construction of the phantom maps still works with this coarser topology.

Comment: You can replace $\mathbb CP^\infty$ by the telescope of the inclusions $\mathbb CP^n \hookrightarrow \mathbb CP^{n+1}$ which is locally compact and $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: @MarkGrant Fubini-Study metric is probably also highly non-compact being а quotient of the Hilbert sphere with respect to $S^1$.

Comment: @GustavoGranja could you please elaborate? Especially for somebody who is used to general topology as opposed to the constructions common in algebraic topology.

Comment: The mapping telescope of a sequence of maps is defined in section 3F in Hatcher and a relevant special case is used in the proof of Lemma 2.34 in Hatcher. It's homology groups or homotopy groups are computed by applying the homology or homotopy group functor to the sequence of maps and taking the colimit. Thus when $M$ has the homotopy type of a cell complex, the canonical map from the mapping telescope to $M$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Answer (score 6):

The extent to which the answer to your question is no is analysed by Milnor's exact sequence. You can write $M$ as the colimit of a sequence $M_n \subset M_{n+1}$ of cofibrations with $M_n$ compact (at least if $M$ is a manifold but much more generally). Then there is a "short exact sequence" of pointed sets 
$$
\{1\} \to \textstyle{\lim^1_n} [\Sigma M_n, N]_* \to [M,N]_* \to \lim_n [M_n,N]_* \to \ast
$$ 
(in the usual sense that the map of pointed sets on the right is surjective and its fibers are orbits of the action of the group $\lim^1$ which acts on the set in the middle). Brayton Gray used this sequence to construct the example that Mark Grant mentions in the comments above in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938366900085) (since $S^3$ is simply connected there is no difference between pointed and unpointed homotopy classes).

Another reference for the Milnor exact sequence is Bousfield and Kan, Homotopy Limits, Completions and Localizations, Corollary IX.3.3.

**Edit** Regarding the second question: under the assumptions, $N$ has trivial homotopy groups, i.e. it is weakly contractible. Therefore, if it has the homotopy type of a cell complex (for instance if it is a manifold) then it is contractible.